# Simple Exponential Smoothing graph Interpretation

Tags: time-series

[image]

What is the Observed graph? Is it for train data?
What is the Level graph? Is it for test data?

[image]

In Simple exponential smoothing, just by looking at the graph below, how can we know whether it is a good model or not?

Regards
David

Comment: Hi: you could calculate some metric like mean square error  ( or whatever one floats your boat ),  see what you get. then, compare it to the same metric using some other method. Note that SES assumes a constant mean and no trend and no seasonality so if there is either trend or seasonlity in your series, you'll need to use more complex models.